# Oracle 11 table design for better performance for reports?

Tags: oracle, database-design

We have a requirement to design a report page.

A few factors we have are:

1. number of fields in report is 70
2. computed fields is going to around 14*8 (based on toggles)
3. a filter is going to have around 30 fields

Given this we have decided to come up with a physical table only for the computed fields.
Question I have is for performance purpose, is it better to fetch the 14*8 as columns given the huge data size or is it better to have this as 14 columns and 8 rows.

Comment: Do you use a star-schema?

Comment: Yes we are planning to use star-schema to store the results

Comment: I don't understand this: "is it better to fetch the 14*8 as columns given the huge data size or is it better to have this as 14 columns and 8 rows", can you explain more?

Comment: We want to generate a report for pricing. This report will have 3 sets of toggles at the top. For the permutation and combination of this toggles the value changes. These values are computed. Based on the toggles the 14 columns will have different computation. There are 2 options available, either to have all the toggle values stored in a single row in the new table or have the 8 value sets correspondinng to toggles in separate row. For performance which will be better